# Errors when trying to use vget (video downloading API)

Tags: java, api, exception, youtube, download

I'm trying to use the vget API from axet to download a youtube video with Java, but when I go to run the program, it just sits idle for a minute, doing nothing, then throws this exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeParser$DecryptSignature.s(YouTubeParser.java:82)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeParser$DecryptSignature.decrypt(YouTubeParser.java:110)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeParser.extractUrlEncodedVideos(YouTubeParser.java:536)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeParser.extractEmbedded(YouTubeParser.java:366)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeParser.extractLinks(YouTubeParser.java:192)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeParser.extract(YouTubeParser.java:556)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.info.VGetParser.info(VGetParser.java:16)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.VGet.retry(VGet.java:169)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.VGet.extract(VGet.java:306)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.VGet.download(VGet.java:373)
at main.java.com.github.axet.vget.VGet.download(VGet.java:80)
```

I searched and it looks like someone else solved an error similar to this, but the download to his updated files expired (and the class file he posted has references to things that don't exist, so I'm assuming they were in the download as well).

It seems that his fix is outdated though, because the date on his post is way before the date on the most recent vget version. Regardless, that post is here, if it helps:
[How to download Youtube video in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198185/how-to-download-youtube-video-in-java#comment40198568_19198757)

**Here is the vget project on GitHub:** https://github.com/axet/vget

I've been at this for days, and still can't figure it out. This seems like the perfect library to use but I can't seem to get it to work. If anything is unclear I'll try to answer the best I can in the comments. Thanks for your time.